# How to sort a list of last names alphabetically using the sort method

Tags: javascript, sorting, fs, alphabetical

I want to sort a list of students by their names alphabetically then print out that list with their first names included.

I have tried different methods with the sort() function but I cannot get it to work.

My Code:

```
const students = require('./students1.json');
const fs = require('fs');

for (let student of students) {
    let NetID = student.netid;

    var lastname = student.lastName;
    lastname.sort();
    let name = student.firstName + " " + student.lastName;
}
```

An example of what I want to sort

```
{
    "netid": "tc4015",
    "firstName": "Ryan",
    "lastName": "Howell",
    "email": "seersucker1910@outlook.com",
    "password": "R3K[Iy0+"
  },
  {
    "netid": "tb0986",
    "firstName": "Michal",
    "lastName": "Aguirre",
    "email": "agaty2027@yahoo.com",
    "password": "2Gk,Lx7M"
  },
  {
    "netid": "cw3337",
    "firstName": "Deangelo",
    "lastName": "Lane",
    "email": "harpy1986@live.com",
    "password": "lolSIU{/"
  },
```

I need to first sort the last names alphabetically then print out the list with first and last name in that order.
For example, with the previous names I want to get a list like:

Names:

Michal Aguirre

Ryan Howell

Deangelo Lane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort, then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the names:

```js
const arr = [{
    "netid": "tc4015",
    "firstName": "Ryan",
    "lastName": "Howell",
    "email": "seersucker1910@outlook.com",
    "password": "R3K[Iy0+"
  },
  {
    "netid": "tb0986",
    "firstName": "Michal",
    "lastName": "Aguirre",
    "email": "agaty2027@yahoo.com",
    "password": "2Gk,Lx7M"
  },
  {
    "netid": "cw3337",
    "firstName": "Deangelo",
    "lastName": "Lane",
    "email": "harpy1986@live.com",
    "password": "lolSIU{/"
  }
];

const names = arr.sort(({ lastName: a }, { lastName: b }) => a.localeCompare(b)).map(({ firstName, lastName }) => `${firstName} ${lastName}`);

console.log(names);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I think, you need a `map()` too, to get the list of `full names`.

Comment: Oh yes @Shidersz, didn't see that

Comment: Fixed @Shidersz.